# Batch - How to wait for process with specific name so start and finish?

Tags: java, batch-file, process

I'm creating a launch script to start a game launcher which requires a specific Java version. It currently looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Enabling Java 7...
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
echo Active Java version location: %JAVA_HOME%
echo Starting ATLauncher...
start /wait ATLauncher.exe
echo Launcher started!
```

It just sets the Java version to Java 7 (changes the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the path to the Java 7 jre) and starts the game launcher (`ATLauncher.exe`) and waits for it to finish. This does what I want it to, except one thing: The process `ATLauncher.exe` is just a "starter" which starts a debug console and a Java application, which prompts the user to select something to play, and then starts the selected application.

This brings two problems:
1: All applications started after the `ATLauncher.exe` process are Java programs, so their process names are just `javaw.exe`, so it's hard to identify them.
2: The batch file closes when the `ATLauncher.exe` process stops (which is what I expect), but I want it to run until the last of the launched Java processes has been terminated, and then run some more commands, and then stop.

Here is the "flow" I want to achieve:

1. The script is started.
2. The `JAVA_HOME` variable is changed.
3. The process `ATLauncher.exe` starts.
4. The process `ATLauncher.exe` starts two `javaw.exe` processes.
5. The process `ATLauncher.exe` stops.
6. One of the `javaw.exe` processes starts a 3rd `javaw.exe` process.
7. The 3rd `javaw.exe` process stops.
8. The 1st and 2nd `javaw.exe` eventually stops, or the "flow" begins from step 6 again.
9. The script executes some more commands and stops.

I hope this is clear enough! Just tell me if I have to explain something a bit clearer!

Thanks!

Comment: Your batch file expects that Java 1.7.x is installed at a fixed location. But it could be that Java 1.6.x or 1.8.x is installed or no Java is installed at all. 32-bit Java is installed by default on Windows 7 x64 in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` instead of `%ProgramFiles%`. And while most users install Java into default location, the user has the choice to install it anywhere during installation. So better would be to first check if and which Java version is installed and where is Java installed. All Java version related information can be found in Windows registry using `reg.exe query` commands.

Comment: @Mofi It is installed on the path I've written, so that works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:loop
rem wait 4 sec
ping -n 5 localhost >nul
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME EQ javaw.exe" /fi "STATUS EQ RUNNING" | find /i "javaw.exe" > nul && goto:loop
rem more commands here
```

Comment: What is `ping -n 5 localhost > nul` for?

Comment: Also, should i replace `IMAGENAME` with something else?

Comment: `ping -n 5`  stops the program for 4 sec. `IMAGENAME` is part of the `tasklist` command. Write `tasklist /?` on the command prompt to get syntax help.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest solution to one of your problem of identifying java process 
While starting your java application provide JVM argument with -D option
something like this

 java -Dappname="appname" classname

Later on while searching your application through ps or some other command put a grep on appname.

 hope this helps.